# Type for non-false, aka truthy

Tags: typescript, tsc, truthy

In TypeScript, is there a type for truthy?

I have this method:

```js
Object.keys(lck.lockholders).length;
    enqueue(k: any, obj?: any): void
```

I think with TS there is a way to check for empty strings `''`, by the way.

And I want to convert it to:

```js
    enqueue(k: Truthy, obj?: any): void
```

except I don't know how to define the type for Truthy.

The reason I want this is that I don't want users to pass in `null`, `undefined`, `''`, etc, as the key to a hash.

Comment: Beware that `string` would not be convertible to such a type (since `''` is falsy but is a `string`), limiting its usefulness.

Comment: It seems like that's something you'd want to check at runtime. A Truthy type feels a little out of scope for TS

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this but it's interesting.  In all honesty the short answer is: TypeScript isn't geared for this and you'd probably be better off doing runtime checks and documenting your code so that developers are aware that the `k` param should be truthy.  Still, if you're set on trying to force TypeScript to do something like this, read on:

---

Note: for the below to work, turn on the `strictNullChecks` compiler option.  It's kind of necessary, since being unable to distinguish `Truthy` from `Truthy | null | undefined` would be a problem.

You can *almost* define [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), which is like

```
type Falsy = false | 0 | "" | null | undefined
```

except `NaN` is also falsy, and TypeScript doesn't have a numeric literal for `NaN` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#15135](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15135)).

Even if you have `Falsy` as above, there are no *negated types* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#4196](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196)) in TypeScript, so there's no way to express `Truthy` as "everything but `Falsy`".

You could try to use use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to exclude possibly-falsy parameters in `enqueue()`, but it is weird:

```
type DefinitelyTruthy<T> =
  false extends T ? never :
  0 extends T ? never :
  "" extends T ? never :
  null extends T ? never :
  undefined extends T ? never :
  T

declare function enqueue<T extends number | string | true | object>(
  k: T & DefinitelyTruthy<T>,
  obj?: any
): void

declare const str: string;
enqueue(str); // error, might be falsy
enqueue("a"); // okay
enqueue(1); // okay
enqueue(0); // error
enqueue(NaN); // error
enqueue(true); // okay
enqueue(false); // error
enqueue([]); //okay
enqueue({a: "hello"}); // okay
enqueue({}); // error, interpreted as type {} which could be an empty string:
const zilch = "" as {};
enqueue(zilch); // error, see?
```

Note how it won't allow anything which it thinks *might* be falsy, which is possibly what you are trying to achieve.  Can't tell.

---

#### Update

I see you edited the question to clarify that the `k` parameter should really be a `string` (or possibly a `symbol`) and that the only value you need to exclude is the empty string `""`.  In that case you could simplify the above to:

```
type DefinitelyNotEmptyString<T> = "" extends T ? never : T

declare function enqueue<T extends string | symbol>(
  k: T & DefinitelyNotEmptyString<T>,
  obj?: any
): void

enqueue(""); // error
enqueue("a"); // okay
```

---

All of that is great, but unfortunately there's the problem that if you pass a general `string` to `enqueue()` it will fail, and sometimes a developer might need to do that if the value they are using for the `k` parameter isn't a string literal they have specified:

```
declare const str: string; // comes from somewhere else
enqueue(str); // error!  how do I do this?
```

To deal with this, you can try to create a [nominal type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html) which you can use to identify to the compiler that a value has been checked for emptiness, and then make a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to constrain a `string` to that type:

```
type NotEmptyString = string & {"***NotEmptyString***": true};
function notEmptyString(x: string): x is NotEmptyString {
  return x !== "";
}
```

Now the developer can do this:

```
declare const str: string;
enqueue(str); // error, might be falsy
if (notEmptyString(str)) {
  enqueue(str); // okay, str is NotEmptyString
}
```

---

Whew!  That's a lot of hoop jumping.  It's up to you if you think this is worth it.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I tried this in the [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) but it's erroring for everything. For example `enqueue("a")` gives the error `Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

Comment: Turn on `--strictNullChecks`... you probably need that anyway if you're trying to distinguish between `undefined`/`null` and truthy things.

Answer (score 11):

There is no `Truthy` type, **BUT** you can leverage type guard system ([type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates)) to help TypeScript to understand what really is `truthy` and assign it `truthy` type!

**Let's define `Falsy` type and [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) `isTruthy` function:**

```
type Falsy = false | 0 | '' | null | undefined;

// this is a type predicate - if x is `truthy`, then it's T
const isTruthy = <T>(x: T | Falsy): x is T => !!x;
```

Now we can use our `isTruthy` function to find `Truthy` values and TypeScript will correctly assign the `"truthy"` type to the result.

**Examples:**

```
{   // removing boolean "false" type
  const result: string | false = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'a' : false;
  const truthyResult: string = isTruthy(result) ? result : 'was false';
}
{   // filtering only numbers from array
  const result: (number | undefined)[] = [42, undefined, 8, 16];
  const truthyResult: number[] = result.filter(isTruthy);
}
{   // filtering only Promises from array
  const result: (Promise<string> | null)[] = [Promise.resolve('a'), null, Promise.resolve('b'), Promise.resolve('c')];
  const truthyResult: Promise<string>[] = result.filter(isTruthy);
}
```

Comment: A word of caution. 0 is a number (even though falsey). Hence the second example would actually filter out 0, a number, from the array, were it to exist in the array.

Comment: This is how I did it before I saw your comment haha, good enough solution for me

Comment: this doesn't help me, I need a Truthy type, not a function that determines if an arg is truthy?

Answer (score 4):

It's a late answer and I am not a TypeScript expert, but I am using `4.8.2` and the below works well for me:

```
type Falsy = null | undefined | false | 0 | -0 | 0n | '';

type Truthy<T> = T extends Falsy ? never : T;
```

Unfortunately I am not able to give a good explanation, but below is an example:

```
type MaybeUndefinedObject = object | undefined;

// Works
const truthyType: Truthy<MaybeUndefinedObject> = {};

// Fails with "Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'object'."
const truthyValue: Truthy<MaybeUndefinedObject> = undefined;
```

Hope this was helpful. Please flag if not.