# How to figure out the TrueValue type exclude NaN?

Tags: typescript

I want to write a type to indicate the function return a **True-like** value:

```
type TrueValue<T> = T extends undefined | null | false | '' | 0 | NaN ? never : T;
```

But error shows that NaN is a value, I cannot reference it there as a type.

Comment: Typescript [has no NaN Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999696/does-typescript-have-a-nan-type)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type for non-falsy, aka truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390276/type-for-non-falsy-aka-truthy)

Comment: There's no great way to do this right now; `NaN` has type `number` and there is no numeric literal type corresponding to `NaN`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#28682](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28682) for more info